# Xamarin.Android TextView disable - SetFocusable or Clickable?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a TextView that links to another activity. I want to disable it based on a certain condition.

I see their are plenty of articles on disabled EditText for Xamarin.Android, but not a lot for disabling a clickable TextView (mainly just for Java Android, not Xamarin.Android (c#). One instruction I found said to use the method SetFocusable. I tried both 0, and ViewFocusability.NotFocusable as values, but neither work.

C#:

```
textView.SetFocusable(ViewFocusability.NotFocusable);


textView.SetFocusable(0);
```

I then look at the MS documentation, and I see a property "Clickable. So I tried:

```
textView.Clickable = false;
```

Now this works. Is this the most appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

TextView is a view which can't be clicked and edited. I tried many times in my project. And I use the following code:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="23dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:editable="true"
    android:enabled="false"
    />
```

The `android:clickable="true"`,`android:focusable="true"` and `android:editable="true"` make the textview can be input from the physical keyboard but it still can't be focused. In addition, the `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` make the textview can be focused and when user click it, the soft keyboard will show.

But if I set the enable as false, the textview is disabled. It can't be clicked and input any way. So the `textview.Enabled = false;` may be you want.